# Páginas minificadas e processamento para cada requisição

Tags: php, html

Se eu desejo minificar uma página em HTML a partir do PHP eu estarei mais ganhando ou perdendo?

De forma mais clara: quero manter a formatação e a praticidade para quando editar a página, preservando a edentação. Mas também me preocupo com o carregamento da página, uma vez que no desenvolvimento ela está a se tornar mais pesada do que eu gostaria, logo uma solução é minificar e economizar alguns KBs retirando tudo o que é desnecessário ao usuário fazer o download da página. Da mesma forma com CSS e JS.

Mas como queria fazer isso com o PHP (gerar um output retirando os lixos), queria saber se eu perderia mais tempo processando a página do que se ela não tivesse minificada e fosse realizado o download.

Entendo que isso dependa de diversos fatores, mas gostaria de considerar grandes volumes de informações (cerca de 2MB não minificado e 1.2MB minificado), o que são quase 60% de diferença no tamanho. Quais são os fatores que deixariam o processamento da página para ser minificada lenta?

Existem outras opções para deixar a página leve?

Comment: Realmente, só medindo a performance do seu caso específico pra saber, mas minificar *on-the-fly* a cada requisição não parece uma boa ideia em termos gerais. Você chegou a considerar a opção de guardar as páginas minificadas em *cache* por um período?

Comment: Não sei se 'chachear' as páginas é uma boa ideia, ela é atualizada com certa frequência diária de forma inconstante e imagino eu que isso geraria problemas nesse caso específico.

Comment: Vale a pena "minificar" o HTML se você quer economizar ao máximo em largura de banda. O processamento é rápido e é muito bom principalmente para conexões lentas. Em PHP, é fácil, basta usar uma combinação de `ob_start` para pegar o HTML original + `str_replace` para eliminar os espaços e quebras de linhas + `preg_replace` para eliminar os comentários. Se você não usar tokens CSRF ou redirecionamentos, você pode fazer cache do HTML no servidor. Mas tem algumas prioridades antes disso, como Gzip, HTTP cache, otimizar imagens, combinar JS e CSS, usar CSS sprites, usar um CDN se possível, etc

Comment: Editei minha resposta esclarescendo sua dúvida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve Minificar e Compactar (note que são coisas diferentes) os HTML, CSS e JS de seu site juntamente com as imagens, porém trabalho com Templates Dwoo mantenho uma versão sem a minificação para trabalho e outra minificada, note que as páginas são dinâmicas mesmo assim elas permanecem minificadas já que o template esta minificado.

- Minificar: Seria remover os espaços em brancos (também retiro algumas aspas iúteis (quando são inúteis, ex: quando há somente uma classe no atributo `class`)) (geralmente reduz 15%).
- Compactar: Seria compactar mesmo, usando Gzip, habilitado nativamente no Nginx (geralmente reduz uns 50%).
- Junção de arquivos: Faça a junção de Todos os arquivos .css e .js em um único arquivo (Quando for distribuir a página) incluindo arquivos de bibliotecas (fique atento a interferências entre variáveis), o Framework Rails faz isso de forma quase transparente aos usuários.

Ferramentas:
[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

[HTML Compressor](https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/) (Possui Muitas opções avançadas de compressão de HTML).

[Compress My code](http://compressmycode.com/) (Comprime HTML, CSS e JS).

**OBS:** esclarecendo as duvidas: Quando falo "Compactação" seria compactação do arquivo em si (tipo .rar .zip) onde ao final do processo (compactação Gzip e descompactação) não há modificação do seu conteúdo do arquivo. já na minificação não há a compactação do arquivo .js e .css (tipo .rar .zip) e sim uma remoção de conteúdo inútil para o browser.

Comment: Agora fiquei confuso. kk
Minificação não seria uma forma de compactação? Sempre tive essa impressão.

O meu objetivo é não tirar a produtividade, então, possivelmente teria uma pasta para desenvolvimento e a pasta root. A root carregaria os arquivos minificados automaticamente, me evitando o trabalho de precisar minificar o arquivo toda vez que ele ficasse pronto. Não estou usando nenhum Framework server-side por uma limitação do projeto.

Comment: Opa esclarecendo as duvidas: Quando falo "Compactação" seria compactação do arquivo em si (tipo .rar .zip) onde ao final do processo não a modificação do seu conteúdo do arquivo.

Answer (score 3):

Você já tem o site rodando em algum URL público (ou você pode abrir temporariamente pra Internet pública pra testar)? Você pode usar o [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/); ele vai te dar uma noção mais precisa sobre onde ganhar performance.

A minha experiência pessoal é que você tem que garantir primeiro que o seu servidor está comprimindo os arquivos que ele envia; isso vai te dar um ganho de performance muito maior que tirar indentação, a um custo em eletricidade e fosfato muito menor.

Comment: Eu não tenho controle sobre o servidor por ser algo muito longe da minha alçada, mas concordo contigo!