# Randomização de classes das DIV no Google?

Tags: html, css, html5

Hoje entrei no Modo de Desenvolvedor em um site da Google a partir do Chrome pressionando `F12` e reparei que as classes das `divs` são totalmente diferentes comparando com o que já tinha visto. Normalmente é definido um nome como `container`, `topbar`, entre outros com fácil entendimento, seja em inglês, português principalmente ou outra língua.

E no Google Drive esta da maneira da imagem (imagem logo abaixo) que parecem ter sido geradas com letras aleatórias, alguém pode me explicar como funciona? Se existe uma maneira diferente de gerar o CSS, se foram geradas randomicamente pela aplicação (menos provável), ou se existe um padrão. Explicar o por quê disso, talvez exista uma maneira diferente de rendenizar e personalizar os elementos na página que nunca tinha visto antes.

Caso esteja ruim para ver a imagem, segue em texto:

Atributo `class` com valor `j-A j-A-Nj a-nf-A`.

[image: Divs das classes]

Comment: Talvez (e isso é só um chute) o CSS tenha sido **minificado** para reduzir seu tamanho (e consequentemente acelerar a carga e portanto melhorar a performance global da página), usando algum processo em que os nomes completos das classes tenham sido substituídos por abreviações. Um nome puramente aleatório criaria classes ainda menores, mas uma abreviação é um meio-termo entre o tamanho e a facilidade de depurar (se é que isso é mesmo uma abreviação).

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr pelo comentário, se encontrar algum exemplo sobre como esse processo funciona ficarei agradecido.

Comment: É meio difícil achar essa informação, já que o Google Drive é um sistema proprietário (não possui código aberto). A menos que alguém use uma ferramenta com saída semelhante, e consiga identificar o que está acontecendo, receio não haver muito como responder isso. Ou você quer saber sobre o processo de "minificação" em geral? Se for isso, sugiro dar uma olhada na pergunta ["Páginas minificadas e processamento para cada requisição"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68379/215) e partir daí.